# Read AndroidManifest file in eclipse plugin code

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, android-manifest, manifest

I am trying to read AndroidManifest file to extract all android permissions in eclipse plugin developnebt but have reached a dead end. It is not able to open file in /Project_root_directory/res/AndroidManifest.xml. I searched and found that it is in encrypted form. 
I can't figure how to read it using Java. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If this is an Eclipse plugin, why not just read `/Project_root_directory/AndroidManifest.xml`? What's the point of having it bundled as a resource?

Comment: So far I have been able to get InputStream object of IFile corresponding to AndroidManifest.xml file. Is there any better way to read other than byte by byte? Or should I open the file in IEditor and then read it from there?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void getInstalledApps()
{
    PackageManager pkgMgr = c.getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> list = pkgMgr.getInstalledApplications(0);

    for (ApplicationInfo content : list)
    {  
        String pname = content.packageName;
        String appLabel = (String) pkgMgr.getApplicationLabel(content);

        PackageInfo pi = null;

        try
        {
            pi  = pkgMgr.getPackageInfo( pname,
                                     PackageManager.GET_META_DATA     |
                                     PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS  );

            String[] reqPerms = pi.requestedPermissions;

        }
        catch ( NameNotFoundException e1 )
        {
            if (D) e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```